# why doesn't home improvement require a country tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

where you are matters a lot for helping people with questions that require regulatory knowledge. for example framing, electrical, plumbing, building codes. even tenet law.

why aren't location tags required for posting any question on home improvement?

Comment: Meta tags tend to be frowned upon on SE sites, they allow a question to be created with only a country tag. See this related question: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250/2196

Comment: Also, our help section does direct visitors to indicate their location: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It would be great if there were a _recommendation_ for a country tag when certain tags are used. Select [tag:electrical] (for example) and a "adding a locale tag will be very helpful in getting you a correct answer" prompt pops up. Maybe that could be added to the tag description (not that people read those any more than they do the [help center].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are plenty of other questions where location really does **not** matter. Some recent examples:

[Increasing the distance from the wall of my pull up bar](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210170/increasing-the-distance-from-the-wall-of-my-pull-up-bar)

[Does a regular (outlet) fan work for drying the bathroom?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210166/does-a-regular-outlet-fan-work-for-drying-the-bathroom)

[Should hardwood floors go all the way to wall under kitchen cabinets?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210123/should-hardwood-floors-go-all-the-way-to-wall-under-kitchen-cabinets)

[Is this species of stone wall-worthy](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210156/is-this-species-of-stone-wall-worthy)